# Move directory contents up one level only if it contains files

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find, mv

How to I move directory contects up one level only if it contains files. Some hints would help. Thanks!

Example to move up one level:

```
├── AAA
│   └── AAA1
│       ├── 001.jpg
│       ├── 002.jpg
│       ├── 003.jpg
```

So it ends up like:

```
├── AAA1
│   ├── 001.jpg
│   ├── 002.jpg
│   ├── 003.jpg
```

This is another example to move up one level:

```
├── AAA
│   └── BBB
│       └── DDD
│           └── 001.jpg
│       ├── 001.jpg
│       ├── 002.jpg
│       ├── 003.jpg
```

So it ends up like:

```
├── BBB
│   └── DDD
│       └── 001.jpg
│   ├── 001.jpg
│   ├── 002.jpg
│   ├── 003.jpg
```

Example to ignore, because the files (and sub-dirs) are already one level below:

```
├── BBB
│   ├── CCC
│   ├── 001.jpg
│   ├── 002.jpg
│   ├── 003.jpg
```

Quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in /mnt/g/test/* ; do
  if [[ -n $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f) ]]
  then
    echo ""
  else
    find "$d" -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir mv "{}" ./.. \;
  fi
done
find /mnt/g/test/* -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: In your first example, in the result, AAA directory is the first or the second directory?
I don't understand your second example. Why BBB (with files and directory) disappears but not DDD (with only file(s))

Comment: Sorry I have just edited it. However I found a quick and dirty solution.